# Php - Get time and date to email form

Tags: php, email, getdate

I wonder how to add time and date to this form and know when visitor send me mail.

I want to get mail like

example:

Name,
Email,
1/28/2014,
8:08pm

code:

```
<?php
        $from = "order@email.com";
    $to = "info@email.com";
    $title ="My title";
        $title_visitor = "Good";
        $message_visitor = "Send success";

    $name = $_POST["name"];
    $mail = $_POST["email"];
    $telefon = $_POST["phone"];
    $adresa = $_POST["address"];
    $kolicina = $_POST["kolicina"];
    $poraka = $_POST["message"];
    $grad = $_POST["city"];


    if (strlen($name) > 0 && strlen($adresa) > 0 && strlen($telefon) > 0 && strlen($kolicina) > 0 && strlen($grad) > 0){

    $message = '<html><body>';

$message .= '<table rules="all" style="border-color: #666;" cellpadding="10">';
$message .= "<tr style='background: #eee;'><td><strong>Име:</strong> </td><td>" . $name . "</td></tr>";
$message .= "<tr><td><strong>Емаил:</strong> </td><td>" . $mail . "</td></tr>";
$message .= "<tr><td><strong>Телефон:</strong> </td><td>" . $telefon . "</td></tr>";
$message .= "<tr><td><strong>Адреса:</strong> </td><td>" . $adresa . "</td></tr>";
$message .= "<tr><td><strong>Адреса:</strong> </td><td>" . $grad . "</td></tr>";
$message .= "<tr><td><strong>Количина:</strong> </td><td>" . $kolicina . "</td></tr>";
$message .= "<tr><td><strong>Порака:</strong> </td><td>" . $poraka . "</td></tr>";

$message .= "</table>";
$message .= "</body></html>";


$headers = "From: " . $from  . "\r\n";
$headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8\r\n";

    mail($to, $title, $message, $headers);


if(filter_var($mail, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)){

    $visitor_msg = '<html><body>';
    $visitor_msg .= "<p>" . $message_visitor . "</p>";
    $visitor_msg .= "</body></html>";
    mail($mail, $title_visitor, $visitor_msg, $headers);
}


 echo "yes";

}else{

   echo "no";

}

?>
```

Comment: isn't mail date/time sufficent?

Comment: what are you trying to accomplish ? the email will have time won't it ?

Comment: Maybe php date? http://md1.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add below one to above to `$message .= "</table>";` line

```
  $message .= "<tr><td colspan=2>" . date('m/d/Y, H:i:s') . "</td></tr>";
```

**Your Source,**

```
    $message = '<html><body>';

    $message .= '<table rules="all" style="border-color: #666;" cellpadding="10">';
    $message .= "<tr style='background: #eee;'><td><strong>Име:</strong> </td><td>" . $name . "</td></tr>";
    $message .= "<tr><td><strong>Емаил:</strong> </td><td>" . $mail . "</td></tr>";
    $message .= "<tr><td><strong>Телефон:</strong> </td><td>" . $telefon . "</td></tr>";
    $message .= "<tr><td><strong>Адреса:</strong> </td><td>" . $adresa . "</td></tr>";
    $message .= "<tr><td><strong>Адреса:</strong> </td><td>" . $grad . "</td></tr>";
    $message .= "<tr><td><strong>Количина:</strong> </td><td>" . $kolicina . "</td></tr>";
    $message .= "<tr><td><strong>Порака:</strong> </td><td>" . $poraka . "</td></tr>";
    $message .= "<tr><td ><strong>Date & Time:</strong> </td><td>" . date('m/d/Y, H:i:s') . "</td></tr>";
    $message .= "</table>";
    $message .= "</body></html>";
```

Answer (score 1):

Current date/time is done like this:

```
    $email_date = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
```

Answer (score 1):

check out [php date](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php)

So then you would set the date to the current time, ex:

```
$date = date('m/d/Y, h-i-s', time());
```